# Ceph placement confusion

Tags: ceph

I have three OSDs and in my Ceph configuration I specify: `osd pool default size = 2`.  I calculated the amount of space occupied in `/var/lib/ceph/osd/` for each of my three OSDs.  Then, I uploaded a large file.  After, the space on each OSD increased by about the size of the file.  Why might the object have been copied to all three OSDs instead of two, like it was configured to do?

Comment: http://lists.ceph.com/pipermail/ceph-users-ceph.com/2015-October/005673.html

Comment: So three replicas is more common and default does not mean active. Thus, 'ceph osd pool set mypool  min_size 1' and 'ceph osd pool set mypool size 2' should help

Answer (score 0):

You should also set the min size: `ceph osd pool set mypoolname min_size 1`

Check:

```
ceph osd pool get mypoolname min_size
ceph osd pool get mypoolname size
```

After failure of the third node the min_size = 1 should be set.

My exemplary ceph.conf:
http://ix.io/1mTX